# decimal price after appliying percent/tax

Tags: c#

Helo,

I am making an application for managing budgets in C#, but I have many problems with rounding value. The specification I got was that the user can input the value of the product with and without tax (in two textboxes).

So I'm making a function to convert the price from price with tax to price without tax and price without tax to price with tax.

So I attached it to the `TextChanged` event of the two textboxes

```
private void txtPrecioTotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!ignoreTextChanged)
        {
            decimal precio;
            if (decimal.TryParse(txtPrecioTotal.Text, out precio))
            {
                precio = precio / (1 + IVATxt.Value / 100);
                ignoreTextChanged = true;
                txtPrecioBase.Text = precio.ToString("##.##");
                ignoreTextChanged = false;
            }
        }


}

private void txtPrecioBase_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ignoreTextChanged)
    {
         decimal precio;
         if (decimal.TryParse(txtPrecioBase.Text, out precio))
         {
             precio = precio * (1 + IVATxt.Value / 100);
             ignoreTextChanged = true;
             txtPrecioTotal.Text = precio.ToString("##.##");
             ignoreTextChanged = false;
         }
     }
}
```

`ignoreTextChanged` is a `bool` that prevents recursive calculations

The problem is that the calculations aren't so precise with two digits.

Assuming `IVATxt.Value` is `21`, If for example we enter `100` (price with tax) to the `txtPrecioTotal` it calculates a value of `82,64` (price without tax) , but if we enter that value in the `txtPrecioBase` we get `99,99` (price with tax), when it should be `100`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try `precio.ToString("F2");`

Comment: When it comes to tax, there may be *specific* rules that you're legally obliged to follow when it comes to e.g. rounding. I'd strongly suggest you discover if that's the case here before asking random people to sort out your rounding.

Comment: Final price (with tax) must be rounded to 2 decimals. The only working solution is to support prices without tax with 3 or 4 decimal places. But not all customers or accounting regulations accept/allow it. In other words - this is common problem for all.

Comment: I'm concerned about the specification because it leaves huge unnecessary room for human error. A user could accidentally enter the price without tax into the box for the price with tax. The form will then calculate the price without tax as less than what it should be. Why would the user have that choice? Why not just enter the untaxed price and let the form calculate the tax? It sounds like the tax rate it built into the form, so that actually gives the user a second chance to make a mistake. They can choose to calculate the tax, get that wrong, and then both taxed and untaxed are wrong.

Comment: It's the specification that the owner of the business gave to me. He first wanted that every price entered in the program will be with the taxes. Weeks later he said he wanted to be without taxes. And today he wants to be both.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate:

82,64 * 1,21 is 99,9944 (which rounds to 99,99)

82,65 * 1,21 is 100,0065 (which rounds to 100,01)

So, there is no way to represent a price with two decimal places that will result to being 100 when 21% tax is applied. How to solve this highly depends on the application scenario (and also possibly legal requirements). What is the user or the application going to do with the value later on?

---

Some possible ways to deal with this problem. Note that this is highly dependent on the application scenario and also consider legal requirements on how to do calculations for certain taxes in your customers' region.

1. For calculated values, allow them having more than two decimal places
2. When the calculated value is only used for informational purposes and not for further calculations, it can be tolerable to use imprecise value.
3. In a project I was involved, we allowed vouchers to have a marker whether the calculations will be based on net or gross value. When the voucher is marked as being net based, then the user enters net values. When the voucher is marked as being gross based, then the user enters gross values. The tax calculations are then only applied to the sum total of the voucher (resp. the sum totals of items with the same tax class).
4. ...

Comment: Try this - `decimal a,b;  a=(decimal)(100) ; Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("F2"));`

Comment: As I say though, if this is a legally defined tax, there may be a correct answer here - e.g. if the law states to use `floor` or `ceiling` rather than `round` then one of those values may be correct.

Comment: Uhmm. I don't know about that. The value is used  to generate budgets, but in the future this code Will be used to generate invoices. So I have to search about it. Thanks foto pointing It out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem this way:

1. Changed decimal precision from 2 to 5 digits in the BD
2. Set to the entity that contains the product, the price when calculated in one of the two textboxes. This price will have a precision of as much as 5. Continuing the example I posted, a price of `100` with the tax I mentioned before was `82.64` without tax, now it will be `82.64463`. If I apply to that value the tax of `21%`, I now get the value `100,0000023`
3. Then applying the format `F2` or `C2` I get those prices with two digits. Continuing with the example,  the result of the precedent step will be `100,00`, which is the price the user entered.

Thank your for all of your answers.